# About $\sqrt[2]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt[5]{1+\ldots}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let we consider:
$$\sqrt[2]{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt[5]{1+\ldots}}}}$$

If the number of terms is finite, how to approach the problem, has anyone seen this problem before.

If the number of terms is infinite, then what will be the answer.

Comment: (1+(1+(1+(1)^(1/5))^(1/4))^(1/3))^(1/2)... something like this i am looking for

Comment: What makes you think such a constant has a nice closed form?

Comment: it goes.. On... i am not able to type the question. ..

Comment: what if this process goes on infinitely...

Comment: You get a constant that is sligthly bigger than $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: how to solve such a question, and from where I can get such series based questions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is not a series, it is a nested radical. Look here and on Wikipedia for "nested radical(s)".

Comment: You could set up a sequence $x_1=\sqrt{1}$, $x_2=\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{1}}$ , $x_3=\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1}}},\ x_4=...$ and look at how that behaves. For example, it is fairly clear that this is monotonic-increasing. If you can get it bounded above, the $x_x$ will converge to a limit. It looks like a good candidate for a simple to prove upper bound would be 2, but I haven't attempted this.

Comment: @Abhishek,are you sure that the nos. 2,3,4 ,5... are all powers and are not numbers in multiplication with the radicals?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The person who gave me this question is not telling me the source and it sucks. He is also a teacher and not ready to share the source.